# Sitecore Brazil User Group: Supercharge your Sitecore Analytics + Sitecore and MVC A to Z

Tags: discussion, status-completed

More information here:
https://www.meetup.com/SUG-BR/events/237927128/?_af=event&_af_eid=237927128

Agenda
18:30 - 19:00 (21:30 - 22:00 UTC) - Networking and snacks (local only - sorry :P)

19:00 - 19:45 (22:00 - 22:45 UTC) - Supercharge your Sitecore Analytics with Amanda Shiga

19:45 - 20:00 (22:45 - 23:00 UTC) - Q&A

20:10 - 20:55 (23:10 - 23:55 UTC) - Sitecore and MVC A to Z with Corey Smith

20:55 - 21:10 (23:55 - 00:10 UTC) - Q&A

Comment: Date?  No, not asking you on one... ;-)

Comment: LOL. 
Tuesday, March 21, 2017
7:00 PM to 9:30 PM

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins on Mar 11 at 21:30

Comment: thanks Mark Cassidy!

Comment: I´ll try to join.